# Proving linear transformation is normal

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, diagonalization, orthonormal

I tried to solve the following question to no avail and will appreciate any hints.

> Let $M \in M_{n×n}(C)$ be an invertible matrix. We'll define the transformation $S : M_{n×n}(C) \to M_{n×n}(C)$ by the following rule, for any matrix $X \in M_{n×n}(C)$ , $S(X) = XM^{-1}$. Prove that if $M$ is normal then $S$ is normal.

I tried to show that $M^{-1}$ and the transformation $S$ have the same minimal polynomial and because $M^{-1}$ is normal, and unitary diagonalizable then $S$ is diagonalizable but I have no idea how to show that it is unitary diagonalizable.

Editing my question: I tried also to do the following (which is using the way of how we define the inner product between two elements in $M_{n×n}(C)$: 
$<S(X),Y> = trace(Y^{*}XM^{-1}) = <X,S^*(Y)> \\ $
But have no idea how to conclude what $S^*(X)$ is.

I will appreciate any clues, thanks !

Comment: What does it mean normal for you?

Comment: Remember that $S$ is acting on an $n^2$-dimensional vector space, not an $n$-dimensional one.

Comment: @FedericoFallucca A normal operator is one such that $T^*T = TT^*$

Comment: OK, so why not compute $S^*$ and see how $SS^*$ and $S^*S$ compare? But you do *not* want to think about matrix representations of $S$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes but how can I compute S* ?
I don't think I can apply the Hermitian adjoint to both sides of the equation

Comment: Well, what inner product are you using on $M_{n\times n}(\Bbb C)$ in order to define an adjoint?

Comment: @TedShifrin $<A,B> = trace(B^*A)$ where * signifies complex conjugation and transpose

Comment: OK, so can't you proceed?

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry to say but I have no clue how I can proceed from there

Comment: The adjoint is still defined by the equation $\langle S^*X,Y\rangle = \langle X,SY\rangle$ (for all $X,Y$).

Comment: @TedShifrin I am aware of this fact but how I can determine what S* is from this equation

Comment: Why don't you edit your question with your progress along these lines?

Comment: @TedShifrin I did as you asked

Comment: @TedShifrin Can you elaborate please? because I am struggling to see how we can take advantage of the fact that M is normal/invertible from using this way

Comment: Now that I've shown you what you should have figured out, please accept the answer unless you have further questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conjugate symmetry of the inner product to write
\begin{align*}
\overline{\langle S(X),Y\rangle} &= \langle Y,S(X)\rangle = \text{tr}(S(X)^*Y) = \text{tr}((XM^{-1})^*Y) \\ &= \text{tr}((M^{-1})^*X^*Y)
= \text{tr}(X^*Y(M^{-1})^*) \\ &= \langle Y(M^{-1})^*,X\rangle = \overline{\langle X,Y(M^{-1})^*\rangle}.
\end{align*}
Note that the essential step, on the second line, is the fact that $\text{tr}(AB) = \text{tr}(BA)$. From this we conclude (since $X,Y$ are arbitrary) that $S^*(Y) = Y(M^{-1})^*$.

Now I leave it to you to verify that $S(S^*(X)) = S^*(S(X))$.